# header() not working in a very specific line

Tags: php, html

I have 2 `li` tags combined with `PHP` that is used for dictionary purposes:

```
<li <?php echo "title='".$this->text['tt-statistics']."'" ;?> ><a <?php if($location == "analytics") {echo 'id="current"';  } ?> href="analytics-dash.php"><?php echo $this->text['statistics'];?></a></li>         
<li <?php echo "title='".$this->text['tt-logins']."'" ;?>  ><a <?php if($location == "settings") {echo 'id="current"';  } ?> href="settings-producer.php"><?php echo $this->text['manage-logins'];?></a></li>
```

If I put a `header()` command right after `$this->text['statistics'];` (at the end of the first `li`) Like this:

```
<li <?php echo "title='".$this->text['tt-statistics']."'" ;?> ><a <?php if($location == "analytics") {echo 'id="current"';  } ?> href="analytics-dash.php"><?php echo $this->text['statistics']; header('Location: http://www.example.com/');?></a></li>
<li <?php echo "title='".$this->text['tt-logins']."'" ;?>  ><a <?php if($location == "settings") {echo 'id="current"';  } ?> href="settings-producer.php"><?php echo $this->text['manage-logins'];?></a></li>
```

The header command works fine.

But If i put it right on the start of the second `li`, like this:

```
<li <?php echo "title='".$this->text['tt-statistics']."'" ;?> ><a <?php if($location == "analytics") {echo 'id="current"';  } ?> href="analytics-dash.php"><?php echo $this->text['statistics'];?></a></li>
<li <?php header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); echo "title='".$this->text['tt-logins']."'" ;?>  ><a <?php if($location == "settings") {echo 'id="current"';  } ?> href="settings-producer.php"><?php echo $this->text['manage-logins'];?></a></li>
```

It doesn't work.

I know that header **"must be called before any actual output is sent"**. But I cant understand why or where am I printing the output that mess up the `header()` between those 2 places.

Comment: what's the point of a header there, anyway? Also, you have all sort of html before that, that's where your output is

Comment: Since you know that the header "must be called before any actual output is sent", why are you putting it in that place?

Comment: You don't have to `echo` or `print` output- breaking out of tags like `?> <li> <? header(` will send data to the browser. The `<li>` and the whitespace either side are considered output

Comment: I did that only for debugging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first character of your example is actually output being already sent.

Answer (score 0):

Your output starts before `<?php` tag.